# Why tilt a violin bow inward? (I.e., stick towards bridge, not towards scroll)

Tags: technique, violin, bowing

In [this recording of Jascha Heifetz](https://youtu.be/Mag2mc5Vva0?t=27) he frequently tilts the bow inwards (by which I mean *towards the bridge* instead of "outwards" towards the scroll).  Here's a frame showing it:

[image: Jascha Heifetz tilting the bow inwards]

I have never seen this done before.  Is this a known technique, with a known purpose?  Is it used by any other virtuosi?

Comment: It looks to me as though it is because his right arm gets better control by not stretching out as far as he would need to keep the bow at right angles to the string.

Answer (score 8):

Heifetz uses a Russian bow-hold. This is almost never seen today in classical violinists and is more common in gypsy jazz. Some things are easier with a Russian bow-hold, you naturally apply more pressure near the tip, and some things are more difficult because you don't have any contribution from the fourth finger balancing the bow near the frog or when the bow leaves the string as in the staccato here.

Mischa Elman was another great from about the same time as Heifetz who also used the Russian bow-hold. [Here](https://youtu.be/31uJT2IKsR0?t=242) you see him also tilting the bow the "wrong" way, showing the audience more of his bow hair.

Answer (score 2):

A frame from Hora Staccato. Must be a reason for using this technique for this piece. If you watch this piece through, he also completely changes his bow hold when reversing the bow.

https://www.google.com/search?q=heifitz+upbow+staccato&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS896US896&oq=heifitz+upbow+stacca&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j33i10i160l2j33i299.13707j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:a19afb2d,vid:Mag2mc5Vva0

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/74923)

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to do this when it's slow, it even is a mistake. But when very fast, to facilitate repetitive string changing, we tilt it when switching up bow to down bow. When doing this, make sure to not skid.